# how to retain to a page after an invalid form submission (CodeIgniter 3)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

How can I retain on that page after an invalid form submission if the `<div>` tag that holds my form has a class "hide" and can only be seen when the 'add' button on that page is clicked.

this is what my URI/URL looks when you clicked the add button on that page.

http://localhost/CITESTING/index.php/gatepass#new-gatepass-form

where  `#new-gatepass-form` is the div that you will see the form.

when I tried to refresh that URL, the page goes back to the default div and hides the form div.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->gatepass_model->addgatepass($adddata))
        { 
            //goes to the default view where form div hides
            //TRUE
            $this->load->view("gatepass");
        }
        else {
            //what should I put here?
        }
```

gatepass.php [controller]

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Gatepass extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();

        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model("gatepass_model");
        $this->load->library("form_validation");
    }

    //create a new user
    public function index()
    {
        //$this->load->view('header');
        //$this->load->view('gatepass');

        $this->load->model("gatepass_model");
        $data['records']= $this->gatepass_model->gatepassList();


        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view("gatepass", $data);
    }

     function add_form()
    { //CREATE
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gatepassNo', 'Gate Pass No', 'required|strip_tags|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('serviceCardNo', 'Service Card No', 'required|strip_tags|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('spareParts', 'Spare Parts', 'required|strip_tags|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('serviceNo', 'Service NO', 'required|strip_tags|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('accessories', 'Accessories', 'required|strip_tags|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dateClaimed', 'Date Claimed', 'callback_dateClaimed_check');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {
            $adddata = array(
                'gatepass_no'       => $this->input->post('gatepassNo'),
                'servicecard_no'    => $this->input->post('serviceCardNo'),
                'item_no'           => $this->input->post('spareParts'),
                'service_no'        => $this->input->post('serviceNo'),
                'accessories'       => $this->input->post('accessories'),
                'date_claimed'      => $this->input->post('dateClaimed'),

                );
        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->gatepass_model->addgatepass($adddata))
        { 
            //check to see if we are creating the user
            //redirect them to checkout page
            redirect("gatepass");
        }
        else {


        }
    }
```

gatepass.php [view]

```
<div id='gatepass-records' class="hide">

    //some records table and default window
</div>

<div id='new-gatepass-form' class="hide">

    <?php echo form_open('gatepass/add_form'); ?>

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Gate Pass No:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <?php echo form_error('gatepassNo'); ?>
                    <input type="text" name="gatepassNo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('gatepassNo');?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Service Card No:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <?php echo form_error('serviceCardNo'); ?>
                    <input type="text" name="serviceCardNo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('serviceCardNo');?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Spare Parts:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" name="spareParts" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('spareParts');?>">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>


<div id='gatepass-modify' class="hide">

    //still working on this
</div>
```

i have this script on an external js file.

```
/********************* G A T E   P A S S   W I N D O W **********************/
    if(elem_id == 'gatepass-window')
    {   
        if(elem_id == '#view-gatepass-btn') {
            $('#gatepass-records').removeClass('hide');
        }
        if(elem_id == '#modify-gatepass-btn') {
            $('#gatepass-modify').removeClass('hide');
        }
        if(elem_id == '#new-gatepass-btn') {
            $('#gatepass-form').removeClass('hide');
        }records
        if(elem_id == '#delete-gatepass') {

        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('#gatepass-records').removeClass('hide');

         $('#modify-gatepass-btn').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#gatepass-records').removeClass('hide');
            $('#gatepass-form').addClass('hide');
        });

        $('#new-gatepass-btn').on('click', function(e) {
            $('#gatepass-form').removeClass('hide');
            $('#gatepass-records').addClass('hide');
        });
    }
/************ E N D   O F   G A T E   P A S S   W I N D O W ***************/
```

Comment: $this->load->view("gatepass",$adddata); user same view to load page after validation error and for displaying error used form_error('field_name') on page

Comment: how can I go to that URL in codeigniter? let's say that I can find a way in jquery that can remove the class of the div when reloaded. but how can I go to that URL if the only thing I know is $this->load->view("gatepass") I can't access the whole URL

Comment: didnt understand what you want ?

Comment: use redirect() function to send on any url. if you do not want to refresh that page then do not write any thing in that else section.

Comment: do not write any thing in else section and then use form_error('fieldname') to show error. use it https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: i tried what you said and I get this 
`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: records
Filename: views/gatepass.php
Line Number: 77`

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: records
Filename: views/gatepass.php
Line Number: 77`

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/gatepass.php
Line Number: 77`

and I see a simple form below that notice.
I tried checking that out but nothing.

Comment: @shanusingh I tried what you said, but I see nothing. just a blank space. am I doing it right?

is my form tag okay? 
`<?php echo form_open('gatepass/add_form'); ?>`
where add_form is the name of the function of the form in the controller.
and this is the URI of the blank space. http://localhost/CITESTING/index.php/gatepass/add_form

Comment: yes, your url is correct, can you post complete controller and view then I can check it here,

Comment: @shanusingh okay. I will post the view and the controller here. I will just cut the unimportant codes there.

Comment: @shanusingh I already post the view and controller page

Comment: @BlackSkull when there is error you want to show form with error too ?

Comment: @user1048123 yes, I want to show the form with error so that they can edit it again before submitting.. I will try using sessions first. before i try what shanusingh suggested before.

Comment: What about the buttons? Is your form have different button like add, modify etc

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your code and need to modify it as written bellow.

1. put a hidden field in  form that contain hash value of your form and then it will be submitted with your form. after getting, set error message in flashdata like

   ```
         $this->session->set_flashdata('error',"some field are required"); and  then use redirect on same tab or div by catching that hash value in hidden like bellow.

       $hash=$this->input->post("hashfieldname");  //hasfieldname is hidden field in that form
   ```

and then use redirect like

```
      $url='/gatpass#'.$hash;
      redirect($url);
```

you will able to show single message in this case  as redirection is required as you form action is different from actual url.

Comment: I'm a little lost. I'm really sorry. i'm new to codeigniter so I'm still a slowpoke here. I'm lost. where should I put `$this->session->set_flashdata('error',"some field are required");`
thank you!

Comment: all this code is for else section of form validation and you just need to put a hidden  field for value of hash url

Comment: even this `$hash=$this->input->post("hashfieldname");` ?

Comment: `A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Gatepass::$session

Filename: controllers/gatepass.php

Line Number: 75`

and here. 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function set_flashdata() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\NICI_CSTESTING\application\controllers\gatepass.php on line 75`

Comment: use this link to understand session https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html and use $this->load->library('session'); in your constructor of controller or put it config/autoload,php so that session will be available through out application.

Comment: yes, all of them should be in else section andi define that field in hidden post variable of form.